# При нажатии на ToolBar поднимать страницу вверх

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

Есть новостная лента, использую `RecyclerView`, как после нажатия на `ToolBar` поднимать ленту вверх?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте `mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);`
где `position` - номер элемента, до которого нужно сделать скроллинг (0 в Вашем случае).
Данный код вставить в слушатель `OnClick` Вашего `Toolbar`.